# Button won't update its style

Tags: c#, xaml

So I'm quite new to `XAML` and I need some help with the following problem.

I have three button which should update whenever an item is valid and ready to be saved, this works fine for the buttons "Save" and "Close" but the button "SaveAndClose" won't update along with the others, why is that?

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    ...
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static l:PartWindow.SaveAndCloseCommand}" Executed="SaveAndCloseExecuted" CanExecute="SaveAndCloseCanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
...
<Grid>
    ...
    <np:NewPartsDetailsControl x:Name="NewPartsDetailsCtrl" Margin="30" Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Part.IsNew, ElementName=thisCntrl, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
    ...
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        ...
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MainButton}">
                    <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=PartsDetailsCtrl}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Part.IsNew}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=NewPartsDetailsCtrl}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            ...
            <Button Command="{x:Static l:PartWindow.SaveAndCloseCommand}" 
                    Content="{x:Static p:Resources.SaveAndClose}"  
                    IsCancel="True"/>
            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" 
                    Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Save}"  />
            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" 
                    Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Close}"  
                    IsCancel="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
        ...
    </Grid>
```

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp.Views.Parts
{
    public partial class PartWindow : SizeAdjustableWindow
    {
        public static RoutedCommand SaveAndCloseCommand = new RoutedCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `l:PartWindow.SaveAndCloseCommand`. Also, I'm not sure if you can have two buttons with `IsCancel = "True"`, most probably one of them will win over the other.

Comment: This bit of XAML references quite a bit of stuff that's not shown. (Given your reputation I assume you've read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PetterHesselberg: To be honest I never have, until now ;-) I'm sorry that a lot is missing from my question, as I said I'm new to `XAML` and I honestly have no idea where to start. The thing I've managed to figure out was that changing the ´Command` of "SaveAndClose" to be identical with one of the other the problem was fixed, so I figured it might be in the syntax or something similar.

Sitenote: I've been handed this project from someone else and I'm unable to get help there :-(

Comment: @LeandroTaset: I've added the variable, but it doesn't seem to have much more to it than that. I've also tried removing the first `IsCancel = true` without any success

Comment: OK. I just tested that if you have more than one `IsCancel = "True"` button, then the focus will cycle through them when you press `ESC`, instead of executing the button click event. So, most probably your problem is in `NewPartsDetailsCtrl`. Can you show its code? You should look for the **CommandBindings** stuff, in particular: see if you have a command binding for the custom `SaveAndCloseCommand`.

Comment: That's not how you use CommandBindings. Executed and CanExecute should already be defined in the Command itself (ICommand interface). Also, please try to fit your problem in a [mcve]. The way it is now, your problem is purely guesswork.